# Compiling and linking in separate steps

Tags: compilation, linker, makefile, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran file my.f90 which uses some Math libraries. The two flags for the include and library files are defined in a .csh file

```
INC_FLAG = "-I$MATH_DIR/include/LIB_ARCH"
LINK_FLAG= "-L$MATH_DIR/lib/lib$LIB.ARCH -Bdynamic -limsl -limslblas"
```

In terminal this works perfectly fine

```
gfortran -o my.o $INC_FLAG my.f90 $LINK_FLAG
```

But when I try to do the compilation and linking in Separates steps I can not do it. This fails

```
gfortran -c $INC_FLAG my.f90
gfortran -o my.o $LINK_FLAG
```

I need to do the compilation and linking separately because I will have many source files (.f90) and need to make a makefile where compilation and linking are done separately. My makefile does not work either

```
 all: my.o
        gfortran -o my.o $(LINK_F90)
 my.o: my.f90
        gfortran $(F90FLAGS) -c my.f90 $<   
 clean: 
        rm my.o
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Don't worry about getting the separate steps to work with Make until you can get them to work without Make.

Answer (score 2):

`gfortran -c $INC_FLAG my.f90` will compile the object `my.o`. The option `-o` specifies the name of the output file - as this is `my.o` again (in your case), this has to fail!

Try `gfortran -o APPLICATIONNAME my.o $LINK_FLAG`.

The same holds for the Makefile.

Comment: I have tried `gfortran -o plz_work my.o $LINK_FLAG` and `gfortran -o plz_work.o my.o $LINK_FLAG` and the compiler says 
 IPO link: can not find "(" gfortran: error: problem during multi-file optimization compilation (code 1)

Comment: Use `gfortran -o plz_work my.o`, the resulting file will be the executable... What are your `$LINK_FLAG`s?

Comment: Third line in my post defines the `LINK_FLAG` as the location of the library files. `gfortran -o plz_work my.o` gives the same error as using `gfortran -o plz_work my.o $LINK_FLAG`. This must mean the linker can not link to the source library. What is the appropriate syntax to link to the library files?